# Unauthorized access to songs folder using but can play using player

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, media-player

I have one player playing songs from "songs" folder. In order to allow unauthorize access by putting the full url of the songs.
For example: http://localhost/test/player/geeksforgeeks/songs/e4bd6e0d-b3a5-44ad-bd1c-52c1c895e570.mp3
I have created an .htaccess file and inside that I have put the code as follows:

```
deny from all
```

The user now using the above URL cannot play the file and if anybody tries to do so, getting the message -
Access forbidden!
which is good.
But the problem arising is the media player which is also not getting played.

Answer (score 0):

**deny from all** will restrict everyone from accessing your website content/files. The main aim of yours is to restrict the files being shown when someone goto your audio/video folder.

Simply replace the below line

```
deny from all
```

with

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will not show your files as the indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if anybody wants to open the file using the URL, like the full URL of the file. Nobody should be able to play the audio file from the browser. But the above code will hide listing only. Please suggest.

Comment: In that case you should not disclose the complete URL of your audio files. There is no alternative way of achieving it. If you restrict that url using Regex etc then It will also show forbidden for player too.

Comment: You have to create a PHP in which you pass only the name of audio file and then a complete url return to your front end in the player. But this PHP coded file should not be open by user directly.

Comment: Thank you once again for your reply. Please guide how can I achieve, the user cannot play or download the audio file if somehow gets the URL and on the other hand can play the audio file. Please provide the reference of the code or URL if any.